# std::cout re-printing everything currently in the console, each time it is used

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, cout, glfw

For some reason, every time I use `std::cout`, the entire content (sort of, difficult to explain) of the console is re-printed, unless I `<< endl;`. To provide some context, I am using glfw to back my Window class, which has higher level std::function callbacks. My compiler is MinGW 3.21, using what pieces of C++11 MinGW 3.21 actually implements. What is going on?

```
void Window::setTextCallback(std::function<void(char text)> callback) {
    textCallback = callback;
    auto onText = [](GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int text, int mods) {
        Window* win = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
        win->textCallback(static_cast<char>(text));
    };
    glfwSetCharModsCallback(window, onText);
}
```

And then in `main.cpp`...

```
Window w;
w.setTextCallback([](char text){
    cout << text;
}
```

When the window is open, lets say I type "asdf". The output is "aasasdasdf". In slow motion, it goes: "a", "aas", "aasasd", aasasdasdf".

However, if I change `main.cpp` to:

```
Window w;
w.setTextCallback([](char text){
    cout << text << endl;
}
```

The output is: 
"a 
s 
d 
f" 
As expected.

No other threads are using `cout` and I know that because I don't have any other threads. This behavior does not happen elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cout` is a buffer. So each time you `<<` to it, you're just adding text and it's holding on. `endl` is a way to flush the buffer. If you want to print only the last bit of text you push into it, you need to start with it empty. [Try this post](http://www.programmingincpp.com/flush-the-output-stream-buffer.html) and then I'm sure your googling can finish any questions you might have about this.

Comment: Thanks very much. Did not know that.

Comment: I just tried `cout << text << flush;` and `flush(cout);` and it didn't work. Do you think it is MinGW?

Comment: I would find it very strange for this to be a MinGW issue. Do some more research into buffers, clearing them, etc. and I'm willing to bet you can solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I will do so. I'm probably doing something silly. Thanks!